# create custom objects using a for loop

Tags: python, pandas, loops, for-loop, object

I would like to create object names containing strings that are in a list. Each object would be assigned a data frame from a SQL database via MySQL.connector. The dataframes' names that are being assigned to the objects contain the strings in the list, as well.

```
team_abbrev =  ['BOS','BKN','NYK']
```

I tried a for loop:

```
for t in team_abbrev:
  stats_(iter(team_abbrev)) = pd.DataFrame(list(all_rows_(iter(team_abbrev)),columns=names_(iter(team_abbrev))))
```

if I did this manually, I would write the following:

```
stats_BOS =pd.DataFrame(list(all_rows_BOS),columns=names_BOS)
stats_BKN =pd.DataFrame(list(all_rows_BKN),columns=names_BKN)
stats_NYK =pd.DataFrame(list(all_rows_NYK),columns=names_NYK)
```

what is the correct syntax?
thanks in advance.

Comment: Use a dictionary instead of individual variables.

Comment: what's the syntax?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries